# Attempting to count unique users between two categories in Spark

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset structure in Spark with two columns, one called `user` the other called `category`. Such that the table looks some what like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|           user|       category|
+---------------+---------------+
|        garrett|        syncopy|
|       garrison|    musictheory|
|          marta|     sheetmusic|
|        garrett|  orchestration|
|         harold|         chopin|
|          marta|   russianmusic|
|           niko|          piano|
|          james|     sheetmusic|
|          manny|         violin|
|        charles|       gershwin|
|         dawson|          cello|
|            bob|          cello|
|         george|          cello|
|         george|  americanmusic|
|            bob| personalcompos|
|         george|     sheetmusic|
|           fred|     sheetmusic|
|            bob|     sheetmusic|
|       garrison|     sheetmusic|
|         george|    musictheory|
+---------------+---------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Each row in the table is unique but a user and category can appear multiple times. The objective is to count the number of users that two categories share. For example `cello` and `americanmusic` share a user named `george` and `musictheory` and `sheetmusic` share users `george` and `garrison`. The goal is to get the number of distinct users between n categories meaning that there is at most n squared edges between categories. I understand partially how to do this operation but I am struggling a little bit converting my thoughts to Spark Java.

My thinking is that I need to do a self-join on `user` to get a table that would be structured like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|           user|       category|       category|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       garrison|    musictheory|     sheetmusic|
|         george|    musictheory|     sheetmusic|
|       garrison|    musictheory|    musictheory|
|         george|    musictheory|    musicthoery|
|       garrison|     sheetmusic|    musictheory|
|         george|     sheetmusic|    musictheory|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The self join operation in Spark (Java code) is not difficult:

```
Dataset<Row> newDataset = allUsersToCategories.join(allUsersToCategories, "users");
```

This is getting somewhere, however I get mappings to the same category as in rows 3 and 4 in the above example and I get backwards mappings where the categories are reversed such that essentially is double counting each user interaction like in rows 5 and 6 of the above example.

What I would believe I need to do is have some sort of conditional in my join that says something along the lines of `X < Y` so that equal categories and duplicates get thrown away. Finally I then need to count the number of distinct rows for n squared combinations where n is the number of categories.

Could somebody please explain how to do this in Spark and specifically Spark Java since I am a little unfamiliar with the Scala syntax?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Write the SQL query and execute it. And any filter can be used

Comment: what would the SQL query be explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a couple of hours ago using `spark sql`:

```
    Dataset<Row> connection per shared user = spark.sql("SELECT a.user as user, "
                                                            + "a.category as categoryOne, "
                                                            + "b.category as categoryTwo "
                                                            + "FROM allTable as a INNER JOIN allTable as b "
                                                            + "ON a.user = b.user AND a.user < b.user");
```

This will then create a Dataset with three columns `user`, `categoryOne`, and `categoryTwo`.  Each row will be unique and will indicate when the user exists in both categories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, but I will try to help.

According to my understanding expected result for above data should look like below. If it's not true, please let me know I will try to make requried modifications.

```
+--------------+--------------+-+
|_1            |_2            |
+--------------+--------------+-+
|personalcompos|sheetmusic    |1|
|cello         |musictheory   |1|
|americanmusic |cello         |1|
|cello         |sheetmusic    |2|
|cello         |personalcompos|1|
|russianmusic  |sheetmusic    |1|
|americanmusic |sheetmusic    |1|
|americanmusic |musictheory   |1|
|musictheory   |sheetmusic    |2|
|orchestration |syncopy       |1|
+--------------+--------------+-+
```

In this case you can solve your problem with below Scala code:

```
allUsersToCategories
    .groupByKey(_.user)
    .flatMapGroups{case (user, userCategories) =>
      val categories = userCategories.map(uc => uc.category).toSeq
      for {
         c1 <- categories
         c2 <- categories
         if c1 < c2
      } yield (c1, c2)
    }
    .groupByKey(x => x)
    .count()
    .show()
```

If you need symetric result you can just change if statement in `flatMapGroups` transformation to `if c1 != c2`.

Please note that in above example I used Dataset API, which for test purpose was created with below code:

```
case class UserCategory(user: String, category: String)

val allUsersToCategories = session.createDataset(Seq(
   UserCategory("garrett", "syncopy"),
   UserCategory("garrison", "musictheory"),
   UserCategory("marta", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("garrett", "orchestration"),
   UserCategory("harold", "chopin"),
   UserCategory("marta", "russianmusic"),
   UserCategory("niko", "piano"),
   UserCategory("james", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("manny", "violin"),
   UserCategory("charles", "gershwin"),
   UserCategory("dawson", "cello"),
   UserCategory("bob", "cello"),
   UserCategory("george", "cello"),
   UserCategory("george", "americanmusic"),
   UserCategory("bob", "personalcompos"),
   UserCategory("george", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("fred", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("bob", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("garrison", "sheetmusic"),
   UserCategory("george", "musictheory")
))
```

I was trying to provide example in Java, but I don't have any experience with Java+Spark and it is too time consuming for me to migrate above example from Scala to Java...